# blueman audio profile w/ headset: HSP/HFP no quality playback - A2DP no mic

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, headset, blueman

Is it possible to run best of both worlds:

- A2DP audio quality and
- HSP/HFP microphone

How to do it with blueman on ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a script that automates the change process  to single command: https://gist.github.com/OndraZizka/2724d353f695dacd73a50883dfdf0fc6

Comment: the script does something with my Bluetooth Headset, but not the desired Profile switch, it simply disconnects bluetooth:

    `(base) leder@home-ryzen-desktop:~/bin$ switchHeadphones
    YOUR DEVICE NAME headset not found.
    `

Comment: Seems like you need to dive into debugging. You can also try the script in the comments with setting correct device variable names

Comment: this script, from the comments of the link in the answer, is great: please follow the first line comment inside of the script to configure correctly!